# Recursive Printing Function in C

Tags: c, recursion

The program doesn't output anything currently. The program is meant to take an integer command line value and then print "Test" that number of times using a recursive printing function. I'm new to C and can't figure out why the program isn't working, I'm not getting any compilation errors. (Still working on getting familiar with gdb)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(int num)
{
    if(num <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s \n", "Test");
        myfunc(num-1);
        return;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    i = atoi(argv[0]);
    myfunc(i);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are not passing an int:

```
i = atoi(argv[0]);
              ^
             argument 0 is name of executable
```

may be your need:

```
i = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that. Thank you.

Comment: Is there really a UB in `atoi()`? Other than just returning an undefined *value* upon overflow?

Comment: @CODe do you know: [`strtol()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) use that for a more robust code. -- else it is an Undefined behaviour here –

Comment: @Medinoc because Code not passing a number string.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan IIRC `atoi()` reliably returns zero when the string it receives is not a number, no undefined behavior here.

Comment: @Medinoc Is this?  I was not aware of this...Thank!

Answer (score 2):

`argv[0]` holds name of the executable, so when You run your executable:

```
program.out 1 2

argv[0] will be "program.out", (they are all strings)
argv[1] will be "1",
and argv[2] will be "2".
```

Just to be complete, argc will hold the number of elements in argv, so in this case `argc will be 3 (integer 3, not string"3").`

Comment: @CODe And `argv[argc]` that is in zubergu's example `argv[3]` = `NULL` (as `argc` is 3).